# jDeveloper 12c Creating IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain Error on Windows 10

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I am using jDeveloper 12c and jdk 1.8.0_101 on the Windows 10 machine.
I am getting the following error when creating an IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain,

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\jdeveloper\home\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_12.2.1.2.0-NS_GENERIC_170105.1224.S
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\jdeveloper\home\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2017-08-06 14:28:12

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\jdeveloper\home\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
wlst > 
wlst > Type help() for help on available commands
wlst > 
wlst > Creating Default Domain
wlst > [progress] Reading template: Basic WebLogic Server Domain
wlst > Setting Name to 'DefaultServer'
wlst > Setting ListenAddress to ''
wlst > Setting ListenPort to 7101
wlst > Enabling SSL using port 7102
wlst > Setting domain administrator to 'weblogic2'
wlst > Setting domain password.
wlst > [progress] Writing domain: /C:/Oracle/Middleware-122120/jdeveloper/home/system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Closing template.
wlst > [progress] Reading domain: /C:/Oracle/Middleware-122120/jdeveloper/home/system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: Oracle ADRS 
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > [progress] Closing domain.
wlst > [progress] Reading domain: /C:/Oracle/Middleware-122120/jdeveloper/home/system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: Oracle JRF 
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > Error: runCmd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
wlst > com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2768)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:701)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.command$1(C:\Users\Selim\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2797536256303688956.py:19)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.call_function(C:\Users\Selim\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2797536256303688956.py)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.updateDomain$31(C:\Users\Selim\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2797536256303688956.py:135)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.call_function(C:\Users\Selim\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2797536256303688956.py)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx99.f$0(C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\jdeveloper\home\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py:125)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx99.call_function(C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\jdeveloper\home\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:181)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTState.processCommand(WLSTState.java:241)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:695)
wlst >  ... 30 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.updateDomain(WLScriptContext.java:1116)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTState.processCommand(WLSTState.java:224)
wlst >  ... 31 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.runProgressOperator(ScriptExecutor.java:5564)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.updateDomain(ScriptExecutor.java:2509)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.updateDomain(WLScriptContext.java:1111)
wlst >  ... 36 more
wlst > Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "C:\Oracle\Middleware-122120\jdeveloper\home\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py", line 125, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Users\Selim\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2797536256303688956.py", line 135, in updateDomain
wlst >   File "C:\Users\Selim\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni2797536256303688956.py", line 19, in command
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2768)
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:701)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst > 
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Elapsed time:  92861 ms
```

I installed version 12c without uninstalling JDeveloper 11g,
Weblogic is running in 11g version.
Some sources say that I need to unzip the jython-modules.jar file and edit the javashell.py file. 
http://unversioned.blogspot.com.tr/2015/12/jdeveloper-12c-generic-installer-cannot-create-weblogic-domain.html
But I can not do the related arrangement because I do not have the relevant lines.

Comment: Problem solved with changing windows 10 region settings from turkish to english

Comment: Where to set Windows 10 region settings in JDev 12c?